# Closing ArcMap getting started dialog using ArcObjects by C#?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I don't want the ArcMap "Getting Started" dialog to appear after arcmap starts up.

I have a login form in my Extension and after login I set a proper MXD for the user. So I don't want the "Getting Started" dialog to appear.

Has anyone done this task?

Answer (score 5):

Wether or not this window is shown is determined by a registry value.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcMap\Settings\GettingStarted

ShowStartup: DWORD:0
```

(The version may be different on your system)

You could try to set this value to 0 in your extensions `Startup()` method. If that's early enough I don't know. If not, maybe you could find another way to change the value.

Or perhaps you could instruct your users to start (double-click) the *mxd* instead of ArcMap. This will also skip the Getting Started dialog.